# error using the QGIS "terrain profile" plug in

Tags: qgis, profile

I have searched the [home page](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/profiletool/wiki) for the "terrain profile" tool but have not found why I am getting error when trying to utilize it.

Any ideas?

I have a polyline and 4 dems ready to run the tool.[image]
Would like to export the profile as an image and excel file.

Comment: When does the error appear? What are you trying to do at that point?

Comment: I am clicking on "Add Layer" with the polyline highlighted.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you just have to click on the line in the map while the vector layer is active. The "Add layer" button is only for the raster layers.

Comment: After selecting the polyline nothing happens... an I missing something with "while the vector layer is active"?

Comment: Click on the line while the profile tool is active. I don't mean the usual select tools.

Comment: it works!, I just needed to highlight it in the toc first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Add layer" button is only for the raster layers.

To get the profile for a certain line:

1. activate the line layer (= highlight it in the layer list)
2. activate the profile tool (in the toolbar)
3. click on the line feature on the map

Comment: ..and also make sure you have chosen 'Selected polyline' and not 'temporary polyline' within the profile tab of the Profile tool (the cursor will change to a hand from a cross)